# How to publish document to another document library in SharePoint 2013 o365

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a document library at sub site level, in which user will work on some files and once they are done with the work they will publish the filess. Upon publish the same file should be published on the another document library on the root site. How this can be achieved OOB in SharePoint using publishing infrastructure feature. 
Is there any other way this could be done without customization.

Looking foreword for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't see that as best practice. It would make search appear with both file for all those who have access, and it is not necessary to have the same document in two locations.

Suggestion 1:

Surface the published documents from the sub site on the root site via a web part

Suggestion 2:

Edit the files directly on the root document library

Along with both suggestions, I would use content approval so the standard users only see the latest 'Approved' version of that document. In case you are not familiar with content approval, you can read more about it here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08

Hope that helps.